# Remove-item from text file using ForEach

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have a text file with directory path and file names (one on each line), example below

```
"\\servername\data01\My document\test.txt"
"\\servername2\hellofolder\10 to 1\files456.doc"
```

Say i have 10 paths and file names in the text file (all different paths and folders).
I want to get powershell to run through the text file and remove all files in the folders mentioned in the text file.

I will admit straight up (i am not good at powershell)...so I tried the following

```
$files = get-content -path C:\Temp\filestest.txt
forEach ($file in $files) {remove-item $file}
```

I get the following error

> Remove-item : Cannot find path
> 'C:\Windows\system32"\servername\data01\My document\test.txt"'
> because it does not exist. At C:\Temp\RemoveFiles.ps1:2 char:28
>
> - forEach ($file in $files) {remove-item -path $file}
> - ```
>                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Windows\syst...FSS0434281.msg":String) [Remove-Item],
>     ItemNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

I am sure all the experts out there can show me where i am going wrong.
I appreciate your help up front.

Currently what i am doing is this

```
$file="\\servername\Source01\Cases\Allegro\Export\client name\Email Collection 17Sep15\Native\00\69\emailmsg1.msg"
$file1="\\servername\Source01\Cases\Allegro\Export\Client name\Email Collection 17Sep15\Native\00\69\emailmsg2.msg"
$file2="\\servername\source02\Client name\searchable pdfs\004\pdf1.pdf"
$file3="\\servername\source02\Client name\searchable pdfs\004\pdf2.pdf"
$file4="\\servername\source02\Client name\searchable pdfs\004\pdf3.pdf"
```

and then

```
Remove-item -path $file
Remove-item -path $file1
Remove-item -path $file2
Remove-item -path $file3
Remove-item -path $file4
```

Comment: Can you access the files in explorer? Are `data01` and `hellofolder` real existing shares on the server?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kaygol. Based on the error message, it appears that `filetest.txt` does not contain correctly specified paths. Please copy and paste as text the filetest.txt file into the question. If there are -many- lines, just do two or three. If there is anything proprietary about the file paths, please change it in some way. It looks like at least one of the paths has `C:\Windows\System32` at the beginning.

Comment: @theo  I can definitely access the folders and files

Comment: The filetest.txt file has the following data per line

```lang-js
"\\Servername\Source01\Cases\Allegro\Export\Client name\Email Collection 17Sep15\Native\00\18\emailmsg1.msg"
"\\Servername\Source01\Cases\Allegro\Export\Client name\Email Collection 17Sep15\Native\00\18\emailmsg2.msg"
"\\Servername\Source01\Cases\Allegro\Export\Client name\Email Collection 17Sep15\Native\00\18\emailmsg3.msg"
"\\Servername\Source01\Cases\Allegro\Export\Client name\Email Collection 17Sep15\Native\00\18\emailmsg4.msg"
```

Comment: Sorry all...trying to figure out the formatting for this site

Comment: If you can do it the hard way with many defined variables, then there must be something wrong with your filestest.txt file. Perhaps the quoting shouldn't be there or before each line there is (invisible) whitespace? Can you try with a new testing file where you only put in a few of the file paths with and without quotes? Append `-WhatIf` to the Remove-Item cmdlet so nothing actually gets removed, but you can see in the editor what _would_ happen and if the paths stay okay.

Comment: Seems to have worked by removing the " " from the filepath in the filetest.txt. I am so used to using command prompt where you need the  " " for paths with spaces. I will mark yours as the answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following command

```
Get-Content C:\Temp\filestest.txt | ForEach-Object {Remove-Item $_}
```

$_ holds the current variable for the loop.

Comment: the '''{Remove-Item $_}''' also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because your file has quotes at the start and end of each line. Try this instead:

```
$files = get-content -path C:\Temp\filestest.txt
forEach ($file in $files) { remove-item $file.Trim('"') }
```

Another option it to treat it like a CSV file like this:

```
Import-Csv .\filestest.txt -Header 'Path' | Remove-Item
```

Comment: Tried 
```typescript
$files = get-content -path C:\Temp\filestest.txt forEach ($file in $files) { remove-item $file.Trim('"') } 
```
And still same error

Comment: From the error message in the OP it looks like "C:\Windows\System32" is being prepended to the paths from the file? I can't see it in the code but it looks like that is what is happening.

Comment: @RetiredGeek  My theory is that because the paths start with a quote remove-item thinks they are relative and is prepending the current directory.